# Howto generate a C++ class diagram grouped in blocks of namespace

Tags: doxygen

We are interested in generating a class diagram where the classes are grouped in blocks of namespaces.

Our goal is an overview of our projects domain landsacpe.

Doxygen has the information about namespaces and classes.

We would like to know if there allready is a way to generate this kind of diagram or if someone can give us a jumpstart on how/where it could be integrated?

Selecting a subset of namespaces or taged classes would be nice.

Comment: Please provide a, small, example of what you want. Did you have a look at the tag file possibilities of doxygen to document parts of the source tree ?

Comment: Something like this https://www.uml-diagrams.org/spring-hibernate-uml-package-diagram-example.html but much more complex. An example would be `namespace a {class B; class C;} namespace a::x {class Y; class Z} namespace p { class Q; class R; }` If I understand tagfiles correctly they are used for linking external documentation.

Comment: Indeed tagfiles is for "external" documentation (and probably not suitable for your case). Did you already try to generate something with setting UML_LOOK, HAVE_DOT, EXTRACT_... ?

Comment: I did and the design is ok by me. But is there already a package diagram?

Comment: I found an article which discribes packages in UML with graphviz and dotty. http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/uml-diagrams-using-graphviz-dot.php